# Local escape velocity inside a sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, escape-velocity

For an astronomical body with arbitrary (but smoothly varying) mass profile, M(r), what would be the local escape velocity $v_e$(r) inside the body?

Using this, I would like to estimate the escape velocity from the center of the sun using one of the standard solar models.

Comment: You might need a lot more information like an actual functional form for $M(r)$, otherwise you are left with some general integral resulting from using the gravitational form of Gauss' Law.

Comment: Do you want to approach this with general relativity, or is the Newtonian limit fine? In which case you would just need to solve the Poisson equation for the gravitational potential given the spherical symmetry of the source, and from the potential compute the corresponding kinetic energy needed to escape.

Comment: @Triatticus The general integral is exactly what I need.

Comment: @kricheli, The newtonian limit is what I have in mind. I have expanded my question.

Comment: What I mean by general integral is simply something like $\int f(x) dx$, there isn't any real information in this object of you don't have some functional form for it. Since things like total mass will result from an integral like $\int dm$ and that's about as general as it gets

Answer (score 0):

(Just a sketch, I'd rather you fill in the blanks yourself than me having to put every single step into LaTeX... :) )

In Newtonian gravity a mass density $\rho$ creates a potential $\phi$ with
$$
\Delta \phi = - 4 \pi G \rho =:f
$$
such that the potential energy of a second mass $M$ in that field is $V=\phi M$ and the force onto $M$ is $F=-\nabla V$. (You can obtain the Poisson equation from linearising Einstein's equations or in analogy to electrostatics.)

Use that (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator)
$$
\Delta \phi = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r\left(r^2 \partial_r \phi\right)\,,
$$
integrate once for
$$
\int_r^\infty r'^2 f\left(r'\right) \text{d}r' = -m G - r^2 \partial_r \phi\left(r\right)
$$
where $m = \int \rho \text{d}^3 x$, rearrange and integrate once more to obtain
$$
\phi\left(r\right) = \int_r^\infty \frac{1}{r'^2}\left(mG + \int_{r'}^\infty r''^2 f\left(r''\right) \text{d}r''\right)\text{d}r'\,.
$$
Evaluate at $r=0$, et voilà, you got your potential energy to calculate the escape velocity.

In the first integration I may have cheated a bit, putting in the knowledge that $\partial_r \phi \sim - \frac{mG}{r^2}$ for $r \rightarrow \infty$. And of course we assume that $\rho$ is decaying sufficiently fast or compactly supported, the latter being the case you're interested in, I believe.

Edit, on second thoughts:
$$
\int_{r'}^\infty r''^2 f\left(r''\right) \text{d}r''
$$
is $-G$ times the mass contained between radii $r'$ and $\infty$, which might simplify things... ;)